# "missing ] after element list" with eval

Tags: javascript, eval

im trying to pass two parameters to a function, "i" being an int value and "map" being an object. I'm using eval to inform Javascript that I am passing objects, however im getting the error "missing ] after element list".

I'm kinda new to this so I'm not 100% sure if this is the right way of doing things... but ya.. hopefully i'm on the right track.

```
...

optionsControlDiv.innerHTML += '<input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleLayer('+eval(i)+","+eval(map)+')"'+c+' />'+this.opts[i]+'<br>';
console.log('<input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleLayer('+eval(i)+","+eval(map)+')"'+c+' />'+this.opts[i]+'<br>');
// OUTPUT: 
    // <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleLayer(0,[object Object])" />Wiki<br>
    // <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleLayer(1,[object Object])" />webcams<br>
    // <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleLayer(2,[object Object])" />Photos<br>

// ERROR:   
    // missing ] after element list
    // [Break on this error] toggleLayer(0,[object Object])

...

// The function
function toggleLayer(i,map) {
    //console.log(i);
    if (layers[i].Visible) {
        layers[i].hide();
    } else {
        if(layers[i].Added) {
            layers[i].show();
        } else {
            map.addOverlay(layers[i]);
            layers[i].Added = true;
        }
    }
    layers[i].Visible = !layers[i].Visible;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to evaluate `i` and `map` and what values are they?

Comment: don't use eval and don't muck with string representations of DOM-0 event handlers, you'll spare everybody from quite a bit of debugging effort.

Comment: alright... so what's the best way to pass argument's within a string then?

Or should I go about finding another way of doing this?

Comment: exactly.  the way you're trying to "paint a picture of code into a string" is causing your problems. I'd suggest jquery with its `live` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `map` is global variable this should work without using eval:

```
optionsControlDiv.innerHTML += '<input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleLayer('+i+',map)"'+c+' />'+this.opts[i]+'<br>';
console.log('<input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleLayer('+i+',map)"'+c+' />'+this.opts[i]+'<br>');
```

You've got an error because `eval` expects string as parameter, and `map` object while called as string returns `[object Object]` which is being evaluated and results in error.